# simple_form_for submit to call function in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

I have a Rails simple_form_for that has a dropdown and a 'save changes' button (among other things). When the user clicks 'save changes', I want to call a function I have in my controller that will make a REST api call via curl. The curl command needs to have the selected value from the dropdown. How do I send that and call the controller function when the user clicks the 'save changes' button?

Right now, my button looks like this:
`<button class="btn btn-primary" data-disable-with="Saving...">Save changes</button>`

Please feel free to correct me if my goals are in appropriate, e.g., if the function performing the curl command should not be in the controller.

Comment: do you want to post/send the form to the controller and then have the controller make the rest call for you?  just make your button a submit button.

Comment: if I make it a submit button, how do I access the form values I need in the controller?

Comment: all the values in your form get submitted as part of the `params` hash.  So you just pull them out of there.

Comment: but your question isn't that clear.  You have a form (Not tied to a model I am guessing), and you want to get the data from it,  and submit that using something like curl (take a look at the rest-client gem) inside the controller?  is that correct

Comment: I believe it is tied to a model. <%= simple_form_for [@firstThing, @secondThing], html: {class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

Otherwise, you're understanding it correctly. I need only the selected value from my dropdown to make my curl call.

Comment: ok so that looks to be a nested form,  and when you submit it is is going to post to either create or edit (depending upon if `@secondThing` has been persisted).   Do you need this form to update `@secondThing`, or do you only need it to do the curl?

Comment: I only need it to do the curl, but there may be other stuff happening already that I don't want to mess with.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming a nested relationship that you want to call a curl command on the member object?   you could do this.

```
resources :firsthings do
  resources :secondthings do
     member do:
        post 'curl'
     end
   end
end

<%= simple_form_for [@firstThing, @secondThing],:url => curl_firsthing_secondthing_path, :method => :post html: {class: 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <select name="foobar">
  </select> 
<%end%>


class SecondThingsController < ApplicationController

 ....
  def curl 
    curl_command "#{params[:secondthing][:foobar]}" 
  end

end
```

Comment: to do this, do I also need to change my button?

Comment: if you would like it to submit to the action, then yes would need to make your button a submit